# PLSQL ORACLE 11g GET ALL OBJECT

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have this json = '[
{
"id": 11,
"title": "1111",
},
{
"id": 22,
"title": "2222",
},
{
"id": 33,
"answer": "3333"
}
]'

I How to get all the object of the array in position 2 (or any)
Result string: '{
"id": 22,
"title": "2222",
}'

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it

Comment: If you're still on 11g then there is no native JSON handling; so you would have to parse your string, or use a third-party library like [PL/JSON](https://pljson.github.io/pljson/), or possibly use a Java stored procedure (though not sure the JVM in 11g has much support either). Showing us what you have attempted so far and what you are stuck on would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own function like this:

```sql
Function get_element(p_json VarChar2, p_which_one Number) Return VarChar2 IS
    my_str      VarChar2(255) := '';
    start_pos   Number :=  0;
    end_pos     Number :=  0;
Begin
    start_pos := InStr(p_json, '{', 1, p_which_one);
    end_pos := InStr(p_json, '}', 1, p_which_one) + 1;
    my_str := my_str || SubStr(p_json, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos);
    Return my_str;
End get_element;
```

and get the element that you want...

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    json_str    VarChar2(512) := '[ { "id": 11, "title": "1111", }, { "id": 22, "title": "2222", }, { "id": 33, "answer": "3333" }, { "id": 44, "title": "4444", }, { "id": 55, "title": "5555", }, { "id": 66, "answer": "6666" }  ]';
    my_str    VarChar2(50) := '';
Begin
    my_str := get_element(json_str, 2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_str);
End;
--
--  Result for p_which_one = 2 is
--  { "id": 22, "title": "2222", }
--
--  and for p_which_one = 4
--  { "id": 44, "title": "4444", }
```

... or you can loop them all...

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    json_str    VarChar2(512) := '[ { "id": 11, "title": "1111", }, { "id": 22, "title": "2222", }, { "id": 33, "answer": "3333" }, { "id": 44, "title": "4444", }, { "id": 55, "title": "5555", }, { "id": 66, "answer": "6666" }  ]';
    my_str      VarChar2(255) := '';
Begin
    For i in 1..100 Loop
        if instr(json_str, '{', 1, i) > 0 Then
            my_str := get_element(json_str, i);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_str);
        else
            goto end_it;
        end if;
    End Loop;
  <<end_it>>
    null;
End;
/*  R e s u l t :
anonymous block completed
{ "id": 11, "title": "1111", }
{ "id": 22, "title": "2222", }
{ "id": 33, "answer": "3333" }
{ "id": 44, "title": "4444", }
{ "id": 55, "title": "5555", }
{ "id": 66, "answer": "6666" }
*/
```